# compile errors when trying to use struct in c

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef enum
{
FALSE, TRUE
} BOOLEAN;


struct player
{
char name[MAX_NAME_LEN+1];
enum colour col;
};
```

I am trying to set a player to current to initiate it so I can handle it in:

```
enum str_result player_turn(struct player * current, 
enum cell_contents board[][BOARDWIDTH])
{

}
```

I have defined current as a boolean and tried

```
BOOLEAN current;
struct player p1 = current;
```

But when I compile I get the error

```
error: invalid initializer
```

So what would be the proper way to set a player to be the current player?

Comment: Isn't `current` a pointer? But `p1` is not.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth ah yes sorry I should have clerified that because it is c. I have defined boolean as typedef enum
{
    FALSE, TRUE
} BOOLEAN;

Comment: I don't understand. Where is the boolean/BOOLEAN variable here?

Comment: `struct player p1 = *current;`

Comment: Post your actual code

Comment: Or maybe `struct player* p1 = current`

Comment: @MattMcNabb I am not actually allowed to post all the code here.

Comment: @harmic error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘struct player *’ using type ‘BOOLEAN’
struct player* p1 = current;

Comment: @BLUEPIXY error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘unsigned int’)
struct player p1 = *current;

Comment: I'm sorry what you posted makes no sense at all. `p1 = current` - assigning a boolean to a player? How is that supposed to work? What's it even supposed to mean?

Comment: @Mat sorry I am very new at c programming. What I am trying to do is assign a player to a true or false value so if it is the current player I can tell then current player to do instructions...Is there a better way of doing this without boolean?

Comment: Maybe you want `struct player *current_player = &p1;` ... `player_turn(current_player, board);`

Comment: You defined `struct player` as only containing `name` and `col`. It doesn't have any boolean members. You could either add a boolean member (although this would be a poor design) or use some other method of remembering which player is current.

Comment: `BOOLEAN current; struct player p1 = current;` : You cannot assign it. Because it is incompatible with the `BOOLEAN` and `struct player`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Matt's comments were very helpful and resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct player` only contains `name` and `col`. It doesn't contain a `BOOLEAN` member.

You could add such a member to it and have that member indicate whether the player is current. However that would be a bad design (because it is tedious to code and there are better options).

Instead, have another variable that indicates which player is current. One way would be to point directly to the player:

```
struct player *current_player = &p1;
// ...
player_turn(current_player, board);

// make next player be current
current_player = &p2;
```

Alternatively you could store an `int` or similar which indicates which of the players is current and then include some logic to get the player based on that number. This would be easier if the players were stored in an array, e.g.

```
struct player players[4];
int current_player = 0;
// ...
player_turn(&players[current_player], board);

// make next player be current
++current_player;
if ( current_player > 3 )
    current_player = 0;
```